# How do I tell hyperjaxb3 what to use as primary key?

Tags: hyperjaxb

I'm working on a project to import a bunch of xml into a mysql database. I found the tool hyperjaxb3 that works as a maven plugin and generates jpa / jaxb annotated java classes that I can use to marshal xml and suck it in, but it creates its own primary key field. How do I get rid of that in favor of a field that exists in the schema?

Answer (score 0):

This is described in the documentation https://java.net/projects/hyperjaxb/sources/svn/content/trunk/www/doc/reference/en/pdf/reference.pdf

Particularly the section quoted below:

2.2.2.1. Customizing the identifier property
Identifier property is customizable. Instead of generating a new idInternal property, you may force Hyper- JAXB to use an existing property as identifier. To do this, include @hyperjaxb.hibernate.id into the property javadoc annotation (from the simple test):

```
<xsd:complexType name="EntryType"> <xsd:sequence><!-- ... --></xsd:sequence> >
<xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"> <xsd:annotation> <xsd:appinfo>
<jaxb:property>     
<jaxb:javadoc> @hyperjaxb.hibernate.id unsaved-value="null" generator-class="uuid.hex"

</jaxb:javadoc>
</jaxb:property>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation> </xsd:attribute> </xsd:complexType>
```

If you use an id generator that needs to be parametrized, include the required parameters in @hyperjaxb.hibernate.generator-param.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! after I asked this, I found that I had to switch from hyperjaxb and parse the xml myself, due to a change in the project design